# Redirect to an external site with custom headers - AngularJS/OAuth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Is it makes sense to do a redirection to an external site (OAuth sever) with custom headers in order to authenticate the user?

For example, after providing your credentials to `http//this_is_my_site/login` you click login, and redirects you to the external address `http://OAuth_Server/oauth/autorize` to authorize your client.

The problem is that `http://OAuth_Server/oauth/autorize` requires the same credentials you just entered in the `http//this_is_my_site/login`.

How can I do a redirection to the OAuth Server with custom headers or is this a bad approach?

```
headers: {
  Authorization: "Basic " + btoa('user' + ":" + 'password')
}
```

I'm using AngularJS for the frontend and Spring for the backed.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing OAuth wrong. You should only enter credentials on the authorisation host

Comment: hmm, It had been hard to me to really understand how to integrate OAuth2 with the existing app... So you say the login page should be hosted in the `http://OAuth_Server` and not in the `http//this_is_my_site` site?

Comment: Have a read of this ~ http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspects in your question.

First is implementing OAuth. Basically, you redirect client to another side but redirection has backlink to your site. When client authenticates (logs in) on another site, the server redirects client back to your site (using the url your site provided in first redirect) and gives your site TOKEN (in GET parameters). Using this token you can send request to the another site and check if the user os OK.

I've shortcuted some steps but in overall, that's it.

In your case even the user seems to have the same credentials, it is important that he still need to authenticate (authorise your site) on provider. There is no way to workaround this as it was intentionally designed in such way that the client should not be able to enter the credentials of another site on your site and still have the access to other site's data.

Second, is sending custom headers to another site while redirecting. It is not possible mainly because it is a historical limitation. Originally the redirection happens by sending `Location` header to client with new URL and the client requests new resource via GET. As simple as that. Later the JavaScript redirection was added by AFAIK, nobody really care about the headers as it was not possible anyway so why bother?

However, there is one important exception for this rule - authentication. You can add user and password in the URL as `http://user:password@host/...` and they will be send in Authenticate header. However, it has nothing in common with OAuth and is called HTT Basic Authentication. If the server supports it, you can specify them during redirection, but it is orthogonal to OAuth.

Comment: Wow! Now it's clear. The login (authorization) should always be in the UAA server, not in the client.